# Optimise Query SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a query to calculate how many students of a university (divided by genre) eat food categories (for example vegetables, meat, fish....).

Each type of dish in my database has an id dish_composition. I write the query but for calculate all categories uses 711 seconds (12 minutes). It's very inefficient. Can you help me to reduce time of execution?

This is the query:

```
<?php    
$query=(SELECT SUM(uomini) as uomini_carne, SUM(donne) as donne_carne FROM ( SELECT SUM(case when person.sex='M' then 1 end) as uomini, SUM(case when person.sex='F' then 1 end) as donne FROM `dish` JOIN dish_bought ON dish.id_dish=dish_bought.id_dish JOIN meal_receipt ON dish_bought.id_receipt=meal_receipt.id_receipt JOIN relation ON meal_receipt.id_stu=relation.id_stu JOIN person ON relation.id_pers=person.id_pers WHERE dish.dish_composition BETWEEN 51 AND 54 GROUP BY dish.dish_composition) carne)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(uomini) as uomini_carne, SUM(donne) as donne_carne FROM ( SELECT SUM(case when person.sex='M' then 1 end) as uomini, SUM(case when person.sex='F' then 1 end) as donne FROM `dish` JOIN dish_bought ON dish.id_dish=dish_bought.id_dish JOIN meal_receipt ON dish_bought.id_receipt=meal_receipt.id_receipt JOIN relation ON meal_receipt.id_stu=relation.id_stu JOIN person ON relation.id_pers=person.id_pers WHERE dish.dish_composition BETWEEN 10 AND 34 GROUP BY dish.dish_composition) primo)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(uomini) as uomini_carne, SUM(donne) as donne_carne FROM ( SELECT SUM(case when person.sex='M' then 1 end) as uomini, SUM(case when person.sex='F' then 1 end) as donne FROM `dish` JOIN dish_bought ON dish.id_dish=dish_bought.id_dish JOIN meal_receipt ON dish_bought.id_receipt=meal_receipt.id_receipt JOIN relation ON meal_receipt.id_stu=relation.id_stu JOIN person ON relation.id_pers=person.id_pers WHERE dish.dish_composition BETWEEN 60 AND 62 GROUP BY dish.dish_composition) pesce)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(uomini) as uomini_carne, SUM(donne) as donne_carne FROM ( SELECT SUM(case when person.sex='M' then 1 end) as uomini, SUM(case when person.sex='F' then 1 end) as donne FROM `dish` JOIN dish_bought ON dish.id_dish=dish_bought.id_dish JOIN meal_receipt ON dish_bought.id_receipt=meal_receipt.id_receipt JOIN relation ON meal_receipt.id_stu=relation.id_stu JOIN person ON relation.id_pers=person.id_pers WHERE dish.dish_composition IN (71,72,81,82,93) GROUP BY dish.dish_composition) verdura)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(uomini) as uomini_carne, SUM(donne) as donne_carne FROM ( SELECT SUM(case when person.sex='M' then 1 end) as uomini, SUM(case when person.sex='F' then 1 end) as donne FROM `dish` JOIN dish_bought ON dish.id_dish=dish_bought.id_dish JOIN meal_receipt ON dish_bought.id_receipt=meal_receipt.id_receipt JOIN relation ON meal_receipt.id_stu=relation.id_stu JOIN person ON relation.id_pers=person.id_pers WHERE dish.dish_composition BETWEEN 91 AND 92 GROUP BY dish.dish_composition) uova)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(uomini) as uomini_carne, SUM(donne) as donne_carne FROM ( SELECT SUM(case when person.sex='M' then 1 end) as uomini, SUM(case when person.sex='F' then 1 end) as donne FROM `dish` JOIN dish_bought ON dish.id_dish=dish_bought.id_dish JOIN meal_receipt ON dish_bought.id_receipt=meal_receipt.id_receipt JOIN relation ON meal_receipt.id_stu=relation.id_stu JOIN person ON relation.id_pers=person.id_pers WHERE dish.dish_composition IN (101,101,212) GROUP BY dish.dish_composition) formaggi)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(uomini) as uomini_carne, SUM(donne) as donne_carne FROM ( SELECT SUM(case when person.sex='M' then 1 end) as uomini, SUM(case when person.sex='F' then 1 end) as donne FROM `dish` JOIN dish_bought ON dish.id_dish=dish_bought.id_dish JOIN meal_receipt ON dish_bought.id_receipt=meal_receipt.id_receipt JOIN relation ON meal_receipt.id_stu=relation.id_stu JOIN person ON relation.id_pers=person.id_pers WHERE dish.dish_composition=83 GROUP BY dish.dish_composition) legumi)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(uomini) as uomini_carne, SUM(donne) as donne_carne FROM ( SELECT SUM(case when person.sex='M' then 1 end) as uomini, SUM(case when person.sex='F' then 1 end) as donne FROM `dish` JOIN dish_bought ON dish.id_dish=dish_bought.id_dish JOIN meal_receipt ON dish_bought.id_receipt=meal_receipt.id_receipt JOIN relation ON meal_receipt.id_stu=relation.id_stu JOIN person ON relation.id_pers=person.id_pers WHERE dish.dish_composition=415 GROUP BY dish.dish_composition) frutta)";
?>
```

Comment: use case statement

Comment: where can i use case statement?

Comment: Use case statement when categorizing your dishing ... use this query as a derived table to summarize your calories group by the dish...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Should be something similar to this... You will have to complete the case statement ...

If you cannot use IIF then replace with Case

1) Transform raw data 
2) Summarize raw data

```
SELECT
  SUM(iif(x.gender = 'F',1,0)) AS Female,
  SUM(iif(x.gender = 'M',1,0)) AS Male,
  x.DishName 
FROM 
(SELECT
  person.sex as gender,
  case  
       when dish.dish_composition BETWEEN 51 AND 54 then 'carne'
       when .... then 'dish 2'
       when .... then 'dish 3'
       else 'dish 100'
  end as DishName
FROM dish
JOIN dish_bought
  ON dish.id_dish = dish_bought.id_dish
JOIN meal_receipt
  ON dish_bought.id_receipt = meal_receipt.id_receipt
JOIN relation
  ON meal_receipt.id_stu = relation.id_stu
JOIN person
  ON relation.id_pers = person.id_pers
) x

group by x.gender, x.DishName
```